# The usage of relationship

Tags: word-usage

I want to express that the sleeping time has no much relationship with the activity and ...

But the following sentence looks very strange.  Please help me paraphrase this one:

> No absolute relationship between sleep time and the activity,
>   entertainment, and learning time.

Comment: First of all, this sentence no verb.

Comment: We found no correlation between sleep time and time spent on entertainment, learning and the activity.

Comment: @JohnLawler    Because we just make a Power Point, no complete sentence is needed, I thought. Why so much people vote down this post? Lots of people around us don't know how to answer it...
After all, English is not my first language.

Comment: I can't say about voting; it appears very random. But if you had indicated that the context was a powerpoint slide, it might have helped. We don't know your context, your native language, or what any of the words mean to you where you are. Language is not automatic; it's people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without more context, but it sounds like you're talking about a scientific study or something of that sort.  If so, "relationship" is a perfectly fine word for this.  It is quite common to say things like "No relationship exists between X and Y" or "There is no relationship between X and Y" when speaking of scientific studies and statistical analysis of data.

Comment: @Stallman because you asked people to do the work for you without asking a real question.